How can I find the recipe for install the iwlist application in the Yocto Zeus release?
I need to install on my Yocto distribution the application iwlist. I'm using the release Zeus of Yocto. In other Linux distribution I can install it by a package called wireless-tools (for example on Ubuntu or Mint).
I would like to use the command iwlist to get the frequencies of the different channels used by a Wi-Fi adapter. For example the output on an Ubuntu Linux distribution is:
> iwlist <wifi-adapter-name> freq
<wifi-adapter-name>  21 channels in total; available frequencies :
          # Channels at 2.4 GHz
          # ...
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

For Yocto, about wireless-tools, I have found this link which shows that the recipe wireless-tools_30.pre9.bb and some patches are present in the path meta/recipes-connectivity/wireless-tools. In the recipes of my local zeus release,  I can't find the folder wireless-tools under the path meta/recipes-connectivity/.   The same on GitHub for zeus, I can't find anything about wireless-tools in the path meta/recipes-connectivity.
I think that the source code of iwlist is here on GitHub.
My question
Could you help me to find the recipe for Yocto Zeus release to install the wireless-tools package?
It is also useful (and this could also solve my problem) if someone is able to create a new recipe start from the code of iwlist.

Do you specifically need iwlist, and if so, why? Is this for a WLAN driver that still doesn't support nl802.11 for the more modern tools like iw?

I would like to execute the command iwlist <wifi-adapter-name> freq to get the frequencies available for my WiFi adapter in the 5 GHz band. I don't know if there is an other way to get these frequencies.
